# How to find an xpath of element?

Tags: selenium, rselenium

I am trying to find the `xpath` of `svg` next to

```
"//label[@class='btn btn-light p-1']/input[@value='star']
```

https://9qrcode.com/#link
then select Design

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "then select Design"?

Comment: Also, `//label[@class='btn btn-light p-1']/input[@value='star']` is not unique locator

Comment: when yo u open website then click on Design button, you will find pattern, Marker border, Marker center, then view page source, you will see the div, label and input above

Answer (score 1):

I hate to do such xpaths, since I agree with Eliyahu - these kind of xpaths won't be unique...but since you asked, here you go, this should work for you:

```
//input[@value = 'star']/parent::label[contains(@class, 'btn-light')]/preceding-sibling::label[contains(@class, 'btn-light')]/*[name() = 'svg']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//input[@value='star']/preceding::label[@class='btn btn-light p-1'][1]
```

This will get the preceding element before the value of star which since it's not unique will give two values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `xpath` -

```
(//label[contains(@class,"btn btn-light")]/*[local-name() = 'svg'])[2]
```

your can put your element number in replacing [2].

Comment: can we relate the xpath to input[@value='star']???? ie i do not want to use [2], because may be the location will change